# Divisão do Projeto EJB

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

Tenho um projeto EJB, para fazer a implantação do sistema o projeto precisa ser divido em 3.

- O Banco de dados em uma maquina
- A Interface com o usuário em outro host
- E o EJB(Serviços) em outro

Só que o sistema esta todo desenvolvido em ejb, o pacote EAR esta na na seguinte forma.

- EAR

  - EJB
  - WAR

Ate onde entendi devo deixar o pacote WAR em um dos host, e o EJB rodando em outro, mas como quebro o projeto dessa maneira?
Estamos usando JBOSS EAP 6.3 em ambos servidores, a parte da separação do banco de dados já esta feita.

Comment: O pacote `WAR` e o pacote `EJB` serão sempre implantados de forma separada? Você está usando alguma ferramenta para *build*/empacotamente?

Comment: @BrunoCésar 1- Os projetos a partir desse serão implantados seguindo essa arquitetura.
2- Utilizamos o Maven.

Comment: Tem certeza que vocês querem fazer esta separação? Ela não é recomendada mais pois há um overhead muito impactante no sistema. Quais benefícios vocês esperam disso? Eu prefiro manter apenas a separação conceitual destas camadas, separando fisicamente no máximo em packages e não usando interfaces remotas. Veja: [Prefira interface local](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abecg/index.html).

Comment: @Caffé         Não foi uma decisão tomada por nós e sim pela equipe de infra, segurança e o nosso gerente, e a gente mero mortais paga, então terá que ser assim =(, mas nunca lidei com isso. Mas o objetivo da infra é deixar a camada web em um servidor locaweb da vida e a camada de serviço no datacenter.

Comment: Não sei se a separação é uma idéia muito boa, mas parece ser uma experiência bem interessante.

Comment: @Caffé na verdade é desencorajado (e inclusive péssima prática) o uso de interfaces remotas quando se pode usar as locais, ou seja, quando estamos no mesmo container (até por que pra que serializar a resposta neste caso?). No entanto é bastante comum ter esta separação física (por exemplo quando se quer ter controle em escalar apenas determinadas partes, caching específicos, etc.) e neste caso usa-se sim interfaces remotas. É claro que é difícil falar que é certo ou errado a decisão, até por que não sabemos quais as melhorias esperam mesmo com algumas perdas.

Comment: @João ainda me restam dúvidas para poder lhe ajudar: a sua dúvida é específica quanto a separação dos pacotes? É em como vai fazer *lookup* das interfaces remotas? Se for quanto ao *lookup*, pretende fazer "na mão" ou vai usar alguma coisa como spring no seu pacote `WAR`? É quanto a formas de empacotamento/deploy? Ou ainda quanto a separação das interfaces em local/remota? Por último: dependendo da dúvida é necessário saber, está usando EJB 3+?

Comment: @BrunoCésar    Na verdade é um duvida de tudo, nunca fiz esse procedimento em nenhuma parte, na realidade somente a dos bancos de dados a qual já trabalhávamos assim, que são gerenciados pelo container, agora a separação dos pacotes, lookup etc nunca fiz e não achei material desse conteúdo. Estamos usando Apache Wicket, não usamos spring mas se for necessario... e usamos Ejb 3 + JPA + hibernate

Comment: @BrunoCésar quando eu falei em interfaces remotas eu estava obviamente falando em separação das camadas em diferentes containers, pois é justamente para isso que as interfaces remotas servem. Não é tão difícil falar o que é certo ou errado: distribuir as camadas do sistema em diferentes containers raramente (hoje em dia quem sabe nunca) será a melhor solução, seja para escalonamento, seja para segurança.

Comment: @Caffé se você diz, então tá né rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como sua dúvida é geral em relação ao processo desta separação física dos componentes da sua arquitetura, vou tentar cobrir o máximo possível.

A forma que mostro aqui não é a única que existe, é apenas uma que considero organizada e que adoto com JavaEE quando é usada uma arquitetura distribuída parecida com a sua necessidade.

Pois bem, considerando que usa `maven` e também a sua estrutura atual, imagino que possua três projetos:

- um projeto com *package* `ejb` em que estão suas interfaces locais e demais coisas comos `DAO`s, etc. Ele sofrerá pouca alteração
- um projeto com *package* `war`, com dependência do de *package* `ejb`;
- um projeto com *package* `ear`, com dependência dos outros dois (*package* `ejb` e *package* `war`) e sendo *modules* do seu `EAR`.

Caso não seja este o cenário que está utilizando, me corrija para considerar uma correção na resposta.

Dito isto, vamos a uma forma de fazer esta separação. Vou colocar os passos e mostrar como você pode fazer esta separação no seu projeto.

### 1. Uso de interfaces locais e remotas

O primeiro passo a ser feito é analisar o seu atual projeto em busca do que será disponibilizado por interfaces remotas ou não. Existem diversas formas de fazer isto, muita gente costuma disponibilizar uma única interface remota para todos os serviços. Particularmente não gosto, acho uma forma nada organizada quando se tem uma única interface remota, até por que perde um pouco a semântica da coisa.

É bem provável que você precisará de um *refactoring* legal no seu projeto de modo a não ter coisas duplicados e mais importante que isso, não expor remotamente o que você não precisa expor.

### 2. Módulos de Projetos

Para a estrutura do projeto, vou considerar que você tem um agrupador de projetos, vamos chamá-lo de `root-project`. Este `root-project` terá os seguintes módulos:

- **`project4remote`**: este projeto conterá apenas interfaces remotas, nada de implementação o *package* será `ejb` e ele não tem dependência de outros módulos da sua aplicação.

Um exemplo de interface remota basicamente é anotada com [`@Remote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Remote.html) e você diz como quer que o resultado seja serializado, seria como isto:

```java
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface RemoteInterface { }
```

- **`project4local`**: Este basicamente o seu projeto com *package* `ejb`, mudando apenas que ele deverá implementar as interfaces remotas, o *package* continua como `ejb` e obviamente tem dependência de `project4remote`.

Imagino que você já tenha interfaces locais, mas caso não tenha, é apenas algo anotado como [`@Local`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Local.html), algo assim:

```java
import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface LocalInterface { }
```

Na implementação dela pode ser a mesma implementação da interface remota, ou seja, algo assim:

```java
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(name = "yourServiceBean")
public class LocalRemoteImpl implements LocalInterface, RemoteInterface { }
```

- **`project4web`**: este o projeto web, dos seus projetos terá dependência apenas do `project4remote` pois precisará de tais interfaces para consumir os serviços que estão no *container*.
- **`project4ear`**: este é o projeto que agrupará o que será instalado no container `JEE`, então terá dependência para dos projetos. Um exemplo de configuração poderia ser este:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.brunocesar</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>root-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>clean install</defaultGoal>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>project4ear</module>
        <module>project4local</module>
        <module>project4remote</module>
        <module>project4web</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

### 3. Como fazer *lookup* das suas interfaces remotas?

Como você, aparentemente, não está usando nada que faça este *lookup* para você, vou lhe mostrar apenas como você pode fazê-lo "na mão". De forma resumida é algo assim:

```java
final InputStream fis = SuaClasse.class.getResourceAsStream("/ejb-client.properties")

final Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(is);

final InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);

final SuaInterfaceRemota interface = (SuaInterfaceRemota) ic.lookup("nome:/doRecurso/PublicadoNaJNDI");
interface.seuMetodo(args);
```

Sugiro observar como as interfaces estão sendo publicadoas, há sempre várias formas de acessá-las pela JNDI. Não me lembro como é no caso do JBoss, então dê uma olhada no log para poder fazer o *lookup* corretamente.

Para as propriedades do cliente, veja [aqui](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/EJBCLIENT/Overview+of+Client+properties) e também as presentes [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html), caso você precise se alguma das que não foram colocadas no exemplo. Um exemplo de configuração seria este:

```
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming

remote.connections=${remote.connections}
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false

remote.connection.${remote.connections}.host=${remote.connection.host}
remote.connection.${remote.connections}.port=${remote.connection.port}
remote.connection.${remote.connections}.username=${remote.connection.username}
remote.connection.${remote.connections}.password=${remote.connection.password}
```

Em que `remote.connections` é a identificação da conexão, como por exemplo, `default`.

**Obs.**. peguei estes parâmetros de um projeto que já tenho configurado, caso não use *property replacement* do maven no seu build, só alterar.

Comment: Muito obrigado, o arquiteto de sistemas voltou, e resolveu problema batendo boca com a infra rs, vamos mudar a implantação, mas vou usar a sua resposta para estudo, até por que gostei do desafio e nunca se sabe quando irei precisar, já que nunca trabalhei com interfaces remotas.

Comment: @João legal, qualquer dúvida só falar :)